# UPDATED: API Call Returning XML with mix of ASCII and HTML characters for Opening and Closing tags on elements (and causing problems)

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, encoding

SOLVED!!  SEE BELOW

I'm working with an API for a vendor's software. I am making a SOAP call using curl, and the XML I'm returning to a variable looks weird.

This is the output of `print_r($response)` which is the response from the server after the successful API call.

Note the encoded HTML instead of the ASCII characters for the opening and closing tags starting with `&lt;SearchLocations&gt;`.

Also note that when I put the XML below into a variable (using the `<` and `>` instead of the `&lt;` and `&gt;`), my scripts run fine and I'm able to parse and step through the XML and display it via PHP - but for some reason with this XML I am getting "**Warning: Unknown: Node no longer exists in**" error message because it can't find the child nodes correctly.  It's getting hung up on the SearchLocations, which tells me the missing `<` and `>` are causing probs.

My API call and headers:

```
$host = "server.myvendor.com";
$path = "/thefilefrommyhost.asmx";

function send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content)
{
    $posturl = "https://" . $host . $path;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // Not sending
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}

$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetLivePostLocations xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Login>SomeID</Login>
<UserName>MyUsername</UserName>
<Password>Superman</Password>
</GetLivePostLocations>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$response = send_request_via_curl($host,$path,$content);


if ($response)
{ 
    // parse and display
}
```

Returned XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetLivePostLocationsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">   
            <GetLivePostLocationsResult>&lt;SearchLocations&gt;
                &lt;Table&gt;
                &lt;LocationId&gt;1035001&lt;/LocationId&gt;
                &lt;LocationName&gt;Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA&lt;/LocationName&gt;
                &lt;/Table&gt;
                &lt;Table&gt;
                &lt;LocationId&gt;1016003&lt;/LocationId&gt;
                &lt;LocationName&gt;Atlanta, Georgia, USA&lt;/LocationName&gt;
                &lt;/Table&gt;

                &lt;/SearchLocations&gt;
            </GetLivePostLocationsResult>
        </GetLivePostLocationsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So it appears the mix of HTML and ASCII is causing me problems, and can't figure out why it's coming back like that, or even how to work around.

SOLVED!

Well, a workaroudn - I was able to use 
    html_entity_decode($response);

before parsing was able to fix the bad XML and it now works!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what your problem actually is, since you haven't told us which line of code is throwing the error message.

The general strategy for this, however, is:

1. Parse the SOAP response as XML
2. Get the text content of `<GetLivePostLocationsResult>`
3. Parse that text content as a new XML document
4. Extract whatever data you need from that second XML document

Comment: Thanks for giving it some thought.  I actually just fixed it messing around with it (only spent 9 hours on this, grateful it wasn't more!).  I'm not sure why I'm getting garbage from the Windows SOAP server, but using html_entity_decode($response) before parsing was able to fix the bad XML and it now works!

Comment: @916Networks — That makes the (dangerous) assumption that the only character references in the SOAP response will be embedding an entire XML document inside another. Don't do that. The response isn't broken. It consists of one XML document as data inside another. Treat it as such, parse each document in turn.